# Is it possible to take the time derivative of sound speed of an ideal fluid when the background $w=0$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology, acoustics, flow

Context: To determine the evolution for a particular unified dark matter model we use the following equation:
\begin{equation}
    \delta''+3(s\delta)'+(\delta'+3s\delta)\left(2+\frac{H'}{H}\right)-\frac{3}{2}(1+3s)\Omega(a)\delta  = 0
\end{equation}
Where $A = 3(s-w)$, $B = 1+w$ and $f =3/2 (1+3s)\Omega_m(a)$.

($s=c_s^2$ for simplicity). The second term requires the time derivative of sound speed however we have set the background to zero, assuming clustering is due to dark matter.

We can express sound speed in terms of the background by letting,

$$
c_s^2=\frac{d p}{d \rho}=\frac{\frac{d p}{d w}}{\frac{d \rho}{d w}}
$$

However in the case of $w = 0$ we cannot use that expression (with the assumption that $c_s^2\neq 0$). I know that $c_s^2 = \dot{P}/\dot{\rho}$, what is the time derivative of that?
Is it possible to find the time derivative of sound speed? i.e.

$$\frac{d }{dN}c_s^2$$
where $N = \ln(a)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.